# using GeoIP I want to redirect visitors to another link, but I can only look for one countrycode

Tags: php, html, redirect

Using geoIP plugin I want to redirect an certain amount of countries to one place, and the remaining visitors to another.

I do this using `if ($var_country_code == "US") {` for example.
This will redirect all US visitors to the header I set.

However I want to redirect **multiple** counties, so for example I want to do:
US, CA, NL or whatever.

I tried using an array like this:
`if ($var_country_code == ["US", "NL"]) {`

But this does not work, I tried array("US", "NL");, this did not redirect me to the country specific link either.

It keeps sending me to the `else` option.

What is the proper way of having it look for multiple country codes? I wish I could just say `or` haha.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if(in_array($var_country_code, array('US', 'NL'))){
```